# MS Access database in Windows Server 2003 using classic ASP

Tags: database, ms-access, asp-classic, database-connection, vba

I'm migrating a classic ASP site from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2. The problem is that the site are using a Microsoft Access database and using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 as provider.

I have search the Internet for a solution, but can't find any driver that work in 64 bit Windows. Is it any other provider that I can use to access the database?

Comment: ODBC doesn't work for you?

Comment: Are you saying you cannot install software on the new server? Why not install new OLEDB drivers?

Comment: The problem is that I don't find what to install.

Comment: You could install this: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) But then you would have to change your connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

I changed the connections string to

```
"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=c:\database.mdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd="
```

Then I enable 32 bits application. See http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/using-classic-asp-with-microsoft-access-databases-on-iis

Answer (score 1):

For run ASP application on 64 bit machine

Please change the application pool which is using for this Website to Enable 32 bit = true (don't know the exact property name) in IIS