# ASP Classic Error: 3265 Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal. on Database connection

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, database-connection

I am not sure why the following error is occurring?

is it the error on database connection?

Following code is showing this error

Error:

```
3265 Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
```

Code:

```
MM_connUsers_STRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath ("/data/base/path/database.mdb") &"; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxx;"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Response.write(Err.Number)
  response.write(Err.description)
  response.write("<br>")
end if
```

Comment: Perhaps it can't find the database - is the `.mdb` file name correct, and also is the path to it correct? It sounds like it can't find the database you're trying to connect to.

Comment: This error *usually* indicates that there is an issue with the SQL. Show us the SQL or test it in your database first before putting it into your code.

Comment: @Paul Actually I found the solution. on IIS , 32 bit option was false on Application pool so that's why it was showing this error.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access database in Windows Server 2003 using classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139036/ms-access-database-in-windows-server-2003-using-classic-asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your reply and comments.
 But here is how I fixed it.

On IIS  'Application pool' setting 32 bit option was 'false' so that's why it was showing this error.I changed it to true and its starts working.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a "Select" below and you are triying to get an item not in the select.

like:

select name, phone from whatever

dogname = rs("dogname")

since "dogname" is not on the select list you get that error